# Javascript - get specified bit value as int without using Number(n).toString(2)

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, bitmask

In javascript you can set and clear an individual bit value without having to use `Number(n).toString(2)`

```
const setBit = (num, position) => {
  let mask = 1 << position
  return num |= mask
}

const clearBit = (num, position) => {
  let mask = ~(1 << position)
  return num &= mask
}
```

Is it possible to get a bit value in a similar way without having to call `toString`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending what the result should be. Is a boolean return enough? to check if the Bit at a specified position is set. Or should the output be of the whole number?

```js
const getBit = (num, position) => {
  return (num & (2**position)) > 0;
}

console.info("Number ", 2, " on postion ", 1, getBit (2,1))
console.info("Number ", 2, " on postion ",0 , getBit (2,0))
```

Comment: This looks great! Looks like you could even tweak it to return an int:

`const getBit = (num, position) => +!!(num & (2**position))`

Answer (score 2):

```js
const getBit = (num, position) => num >> position & 1; 

console.log( getBit(0b1010, 1) )
```

Comment: for bitwise operations, it is more concise.